# Populating DataGridView using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, directoryservices

I have a list of directory entries in `SearchResultCollection`.
something like:

```
SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();
```

I need something like:

```
dgvItems.datasource = [... something ... ]
```

Right now, I am using foreach to iterate through the collection and insert one row at a time to the `DataGridView`, like this :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dgvItems.datasource = dt;
foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
{    
.
.
dt.rows.add(sAMAccountName, sn, givenName);
}
```

This is a slow, because the src in a big table. Is there a way to speed things up using **lambdas** or **linq**?

Comment: LINQ does not speed up your code, in fact it probably will slow it down because it has more overhead. It's pretty much doing the same loop as you are currently executing.

Comment: You may want to run the DGV in virtual mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx

Comment: @Peter are you certain this question is about asp.net? The op tagged with datagridview and mentions that winform control in the question. Your answer and edit appear incorrect.

Comment: @DavidHall -... woops.  Not sure what I was thinking... Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I don't know what `SearchResultCollection` is, but it may be enough to do `dgvItems.datasource = src`.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will definitely not speed up your code. Whether you use lambdas/LINQ or not, the end result is the same: the items are added one by one to the DataGridView.

I suspect that the slow behavior may be due to the fact that every time you add an item, the DataGridView object performs some expensive UI operations (e.g. redraws itself, calculates the scrollbar position).

If this is what's causing the problem, try hiding the DataGridView before you add the items and making it visible again once all items are added.

Alternatively, you may try preparing the DataTable in advance and assigning it to the DataGridView's DataSource property once all the data is ready.

Hope this helps.